# How do I migrate a SharePoint 2010 site to a new server and new SQL instance

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, migration, sharepoint-2010

I have a SharePoint 2010 site on a test server and database.
I would like to move my site to a production server and a new SQL instance.
What is the best way to do this?

Was really easy, here are the PowerShell commands for exporting and importing.

```
Export-SPWeb -Identity http://OLDSITE/ -Path \\SERVER\backup\sharepoint\SiteExport.cmp -IncludeUserSecurity -IncludeVersions All -Verbose
```

```
Import-SPWeb -Identity http://NEWSITE/ -Path \\SERVER\backup\sharepoint\SiteExport.cmp -Verbose -Force
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you installed sharepoint using a SQL Alias you will need to create a DNS alias/host file with the old name of the SQL server that points to the new one, and the instance name will need to be the same.

- Stop SharePoint
- Backup the databases on the old database server
- add logins to the new server with sysadmin rights
- script out SharePoint jobs from old database server
- rename old database server
- create DNS alias that point old database server name to the new database server name
- restore database backups to the new database server
- run job script on new database server
- restart SharePoint after a ping resolves the old name to the new server (use ipconfig /flushdns to force update)

Comment: Edited question to include solution.